# Get bitmap byte array without header c#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

I have image with dimensions 98 x 102. Size on disc 11 270 bytes.
I need to get byte array from this image without service information.
I tried to do next:

```
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path);
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
     byte[] result = ms.ToArray();
```

By this way i get array with image header, because length of get array is 11 270.

Is correctly that header size = 11270 - (98 * 102)?
Because this result is 1274.

I'm trying to do this in console app.

If it is not correct, how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to get the RGB data from this bitmap. You can do this by locking/unlocking the data in the bitmap to obtain access to the raw data. Example code from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx:

```
        // Create bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\photo.jpg");

        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        // Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.  
        for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
            rgbValues[counter] = 255;

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

        // Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Comment: Edited post: I'm trying to do this in console app.

Comment: Header size in this way is 1078. Isn't it too large?

Comment: The header might not be that big. Note that with bitmaps the rows of pixels are word aligned. As the image is 102 pixels wide, the image will actually consume 104 bytes of data per row. Why do you need the header?

Comment: The rgbValues in my answer is the byte array without header you seek.

Comment: If i need a byte matrix from that array, i can't be sure, that image is 102*98?

Comment: What information do you need from the image? I thought you wanted the RGB values? Use the code I've supplied, your method will not decode the bitmap data into RGB values as internally bitmaps can be stored in different formats.

Comment: You can use bmp.Width/bmp.Height to check the size of the image.

Comment: Actually a need next:

Comment: Actually a need next: i have original image. Some tool can ratate and crop this image. For example: original image is 105*105, tool rotate it ton 90 deg. and crop to 100*50. To verify that it is part of original image i want to get byte matrix vithout headers and additional info and byte on byte compare.

Comment: Then you can do all this with the bitmap class.

To rotate an image get a graphics context to a blank bitmap and draw the old bitmap rotate, see Graphics.FromBitmap on MSDN.

To access the pixels of a bitmap see GetPixel(x, y) on MSDN.

To get bitmap dimensions: see Width/Height of Bitmap class on MSDN.